# Weird sprinkles color

Tags: rendering, color

Im brand new to Blender, so as many newbies do, I've been watching the Blender Guru Donut Beginner Guide. And when I got to render part, I found a problem: First image is dev look, and the sprinkles there have colors that I like, but when I switch to Cycles to render it, colors are getting a lot different(second image). Any idea how to fix this?

[image]

[image]

P.S. Here is the .blend file:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ndjYwAqxHL1UQNghsHvtlwXSDzfF-fOE/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Instead of having users go through links and external sites please use the builtin tools to embed images in your post. See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I saw, you had a Subsurface in the material of your sprinkles. When I lowered it to 0, I seemed to get the color you were trying to get.

Hope this helps you!

[image]

Comment: It really worked, thanks a lot!